# Context-free grammar for $L=\{0^n1^{2n} \mid n \geq 0\}$

Tags: formal-languages, automata, context-free, formal-grammars

How can I express this language $L = \{0^n 1^{2n} \mid n ≥ 0\}$ as a context-free grammar?

I am new to this field and I am not sure what should I do. Please help me.

Comment: Your question is very basic. I suggest reviewing the course materials.

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the material but jsut solving homework-style exercises for you is unlikely to really do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Yuval commented, this is a very basic exercise so you should probably go over the basic definitions. One simple answer for this particular question is:
$$S\rightarrow0S11|\varepsilon$$